# objec is null in Chrome and not null in IE

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have very very strange issue that I can't figure out, when using "Chrome" my object sometimes becomes null but in IE it always works. It happens only for all my drop downs,however, other control like textbox are working as expected...here is a simplified version of my code.

note: dropdrown is binding correctly, so the values are available in the html

**HTML (Using Reactive forms)**

```
     <label for="costCenterId" class="control-label">Cost Center</label>

    <p-dropdown [options]="iCostCenter" optionLabel="cost_center_name"  styleClass="form-control"
 formControlName="costCenter" id="costCenterId" name="costCenter" dataKey="cost_center_id"
          [filter]="true" filterBy="value.cost_center_name">
 </p-dropdown>
```

**TS**

```
    export interface ICostCenter{

        cost_center_id: number,
        cost_center_name: string
    }

    iCostCenter: ICostCenter[]=[];

    ngOnInit() {
     this.getAllCostCenetrs();
this.populateHeaderDet();

    }

    getAllCostCenetrs() {
            this._appParams.getAllCostCenters()
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.iCostCenter = data.result;


                },
               error => 'GetAllCostCenetrs Method: ');

        }

populateHeaderDet() in chrome iCostCenter become null
    {
    this.ersaForm.patchValue({

                   costCenter: this.iCostCenter.find(cc => cc.cost_center_name === this.iRequest.costCenter.cost_center_name)

)};
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "cost_center_id": 1,
      "cost_center_name": "1"
    },
    {

      "cost_center_id":2,
      "cost_center_name": "2"
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: try calling `this.getAllCostCenetrs(); this.populateHeaderDet()` in `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it's because `iCostCenter` is populated inside your subscription and `populateHeaderDet()` is being called before the response comes back from `getAllCostCenters()`.

Try calling `populateHeaderDet()` after you assign iCostCenter instead

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCostCenetrs();
}

getAllCostCenetrs() {
    this._appParams.getAllCostCenters().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.iCostCenter = data.result;
            this.populateHeaderDet();
            },
            error => 'GetAllCostCenetrs Method: ');
    }

populateHeaderDet()
{
    this.ersaForm.patchValue({
               costCenter: this.iCostCenter.find(cc => cc.cost_center_name === this.iRequest.costCenter.cost_center_name)
)};
```

---

## Edit

From the comments it sounds like what you actually want to do is wait for muliple observables to complete before you call the `populateHeaderDet()` method. One approach to solving this would be to use the [rxjs zip](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) method.

As I haven't seen the rest of your code then it's difficult to say for sure but you could try something like this

```
const costCentres$ = this._appParams.getAllCostCenters();
const companyCodes$ = this._appParams.getAllCompanyCodes()

zip(
 costCentres$,
 companyCodes$,
 (costCentres: string[], companyCodes: string[]) => ({costCentres, companyCodes}))
 .subscribe(data => {
   this.iCostCenter = data.costCentres;
   this.companyCodes = data.companyCodes;

   this.populateHeaderDet()
 });
```

Comment: that does not work either, Since the issue is random and not consistent  it has do with timing. in other words  this.getAllCostCenetrs() does not finish lading sometimes. so how would i force it to check if this.getAllCostCenetrs() done loading then call populateHeaderDet()

Comment: sorry, i did not said what I wanted previously ...your solution will work but How can I use an abrovable to check if it was finished or not

Comment: @rgoal im sorry, Im not sure what you're asking?

Comment: sorry for the confusion is there another way to do this. in my real code I have 6 dropwdown then    this.populateHeaderDet(); is called, which makes it a bit messy to have it within subscribe. So in my case I will need to call one dropdpwn at a time from subscribe  ...does it make sense!

Comment: so basically i will need to call the dopwdown b from within subscribe of dropwdown a..then i will have to call drowdown c from subscribe method of droodown b etc...so basically just trying to figure out if there is a better way of doing this

Comment: @rgoal i've updated the answer with what I hope is what you want.